# Get Right value from LanguageExt c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, language-ext

I have method that returns:
`Either<Error, (int seconds, int count)> result = GetResult();`

I need to return right value: `(int NextDelayMs, int NextRetryCount)`

But I can't figure out how to do it.
I tried:

`var toReturn = result.Map(x => x.Right);`

but I get IEnumerable this way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the left case as an `Either` value can be left type `L` or right type `R`.

If you want to throw an exception when result is an `Error` you can use this:

```
var toReturn = result.IfLeft(err => throw err.ToException());
```

But you should avoid this. It's better to stay within `Either` using `Map`/`Select` and pass any errors to the calling method:

```
var errorOrFunctionResult = result.Map(x => someFunction(x));
```

If you want to supply a fallback value in case of an error:

```
var toReturn = result.IfLeft((100, 0))
```

Basically `Either` is similar to `Option` regarding usage and you can find a good introduction here: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/#option